# Changing Y Axis Tick mark labels to hyperlinks

Tags: r, ggplot2, embed

I am using ggplot() to graph the price range of 20 different products. I am looking to change the y axis plot tick mark labels to the product name and embed a link to where the data is pulled from. I am not even sure this is possible.

I have tried this.

```
ggplot(testdata, aes(x = value, y=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() geom_link(
  x = testdata$value,
  y = testdata$variable,
  href = testdata$href,
  parse = FALSE)
```

I have also tried this

```
urls <-c("www.example.com/1","www.example.com/2",
"www.example.com/3") #(shortened here for brevity)
ggplot(testdata, aes(x = value, y=variable)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_y_continous(
    labels = paste0("<a href='", urls, "'>", testdata$x, "</a>")
    )  +
theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown)
  parse = FALSE)
```

Comment: Once rendered, a `ggplot(...)` graphic object is not an interactive web page, you can't click on something and get a hyperlink referral. You might be able to do that using `plotly` (perhaps even using `ggplotly`, I don't know).

Comment: what is the best approach to this then? Just build the function into an html document and let that be the interactivity?

Comment: Plotly (self contained html/js), shiny, and dash are three options. "Best" is completely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Not (just) `{ggplot}` nor y-axis labels, but we can get quite close with `{ggiraph}` and a few `*_interactive()` elements when using facets:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

gg <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid_interactive(rows = vars(Species), switch = "y", 
                         labeller = labeller_interactive(
                           aes(onclick = sprintf('window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=%s")', Species)))) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_text_interactive())

girafe(ggobj = gg)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Clicking on strip labels ( setosa / versicolor / virginica )  triggers `onclick` events wich will open links to Google searches.